# Curious about AJAX being asynchronous and Scheduled/timer event

Tags: php, ajax, timer, scheduler

I want a clarification about AJAX on something I was thinking about...

AJAX is said to be asynchronous - if you want it to be - meaning that if a javascript is run while a page loads and in that an AJAX call is executed the page will continue to load while the server process the AJAX request... So is it safe to assume that it can be liken to a pseudo-parallelism?

Now, what about two different javascripts making an AJAX call consequently. That is, while the page loads it encounters two js function one after the other each making an AJAX call each. Because they are different js functions/ or two different js files do they have to wait for the functions to return before they move on? I think that is the case...

And finally the real question I have... If I have a js function called and in that function I palce TWO AJAX calls then will they be processed semi-simultaneously... Because I was trying something on a webpage of mine and by accident I placed two AJAX calls one after the other and I think that was the reason I had some unexpected results. Unfortunately I was in a hurry to deliver so I didn't pursue it but I was wondering if it world like that, because it would be very convenient for some cases...

Somethign like this

```
function finalizeReservation(){
    var request = $.ajax({
        type:       'POST',
        url:        './scripts/php/reserve.php',
        data:       { 
                },
        dataType:   "json"
    });

    request.done(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {

    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    });

    var request2 = $.ajax({
        type:       'POST',
        url:        './scripts/php/reserve.php',
        data:       { 

                },
        dataType:   "json"
    });

    request2.done(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {

    });

    request2.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    });
```

}

Simply curious.

I was thinking it because I have a web page that records reservations. Before finalizing a reservation though the guest can see the details and think about it. At that period the slot in the database is set to pending and making unavailable to another guest so they don't clash or enter in race conditions (i.e while thinking about it the other finalizes it and so when he tries to finalize it himself he cant or if was careless in the code also finalizes it). The problem is in the guest behaviour, although I have tried to capture all events of the refresh, backpage, exit tab, close window kind so the slot doesn't stay in a pending state if the guest for some reason doesn't close the form the correct way (cancel) not all are captured in all browsers. So I though about making a time limit in the server and if it exceeds it and the state is still pending the state is reversed to free (I have the form on a minute timer, after the minute goes it automatically closes and frees the slot). The problem is that the hosting server doesn't support chron jobs although I don't know much about them so I am not sure how much help they would be and the mysql doesn't support schedulers.
So i thought about making two ajax call and the one to be a timer that will check the state of the slot after some time passes and act accordingly.

Any thoughts are appreciated.
Sorry for the long post.

Comment: You forgot to say what the unexpected result was? Or at least, it isn't clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a specific question about Ajax, but you do seem to have a pretty good understanding of it and everything you said is correct.  At least with jQuery, it's asynchronous by default and unless you use `Deferred` there is no guarantee that code that executes after the ajax call won't complete before the ajax call.

Your actual question seems to be about how to handle stale locks for the reservations.  A couple suggestions:

- Move to another shared host.  I pay $15 a year for a shared host that allows cron jobs.
- Whenever someone visits the page, check all locked reservations and if they are old enough assume the lock is stale.

Another ajax call won't help.  What if they close the page?  You could try using `onbeforeunload`, to alert a dialog that will remove the lock, but that's very intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

the execution of code after the ajax functions will continue, without waiting for the ajax functions to complete, unless the code that follows is in the `callback` of the ajax function.